# Show ribborn after publish list

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon

When I go to route Site Content --> My List , I can see export to Excel button

[image]

It works correctly as I want, problem starts when I publish my list, I want to see that Export to Excel in main view(published as Web Element) too, but no ribborn appears. What I need to do to show that button to public? Regards

I try editing page into edit webpart and change "Toolbar type" to "Show toolbar", but when I publish list toolbar dont appears.
What I need to achieve that I want? there is some JS to show toolbar with Export to Excel button?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean about "Publish my list"? Do you mean add this list web part in a page? I have done a test in my environment but cannot reproduce your issue.

For narrowing down your issue, please check below things:

1. Add another list web part to check if you can see the button.
2. Create a new page and check if you can see the "Export to Excel" button.
3. Are you using IE? Try to test in safe mode of IE. Also test using another browser.

In addition, please add "?contents=1" to the end of the URL of your page, this will allow you to view all the Web Parts in the page. Remove all the web parts which contain the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have inserted the webpart into a publishing page - the ribbon options for that webpart won't display until you physically "Select" it by clicking into the body of the webpart.

Comment: Ribborn never appears into published site, I select item and ribborn still don´t appears